# Yii2 with SSO + kerberos

Tags: single-sign-on, yii2, kerberos

I want to configure SSO on yii but cannot find any docs anywhere. On yii 1.x i have `CWebUser` and `CUserIdentity` class under `protected/components` folder. On Yii2.x i do not know how to create similar setup.

Answer (score 2):

Now they are built-in components of framework. So you should extend them to use as you wish. Any model can be user model as long as they implement `IdentityInterface` and also the if you have `app-advanced` setup you will find it under `common/models/User.php` or in `app-basic` setup they are under `models/User.php`. Here is the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html) you would follow.

However you would like to check your controllers [behaviors](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html) for `access` this is where the Authentication Control for actions is defined. So if you need something different like cerberos probably you need to create a component for it that implements [AuthInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-auth-authinterface.html).